# SevenZipSharp - Append files to zip and remove file path

Tags: c#, sevenzipsharp

I am using SevenZipSharp in order to compress files into a zip file.
I am having 2 issues:

1. When using CompressFiles miltiple times on the same destination file it does not append the files, but overwrites them.
2. I would like the files to be added with out their whole path but can't seem to find how (I thought that PreserveDirectoryRoot = false would do the trick but it does not).

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `CompressionMode.Append` after the first call.  The default is `CompressionMode.Create`.  Path can be dropped by altering `DirectoryStructure`.

Relevant source code is [here](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/56462#364711).

```
    public sealed partial class SevenZipCompressor
#if UNMANAGED
        : SevenZipBase
#endif
    {
        /// Gets or sets the compression mode.
        /// </summary>
        public CompressionMode CompressionMode { get; set; }
        /// <summary>

        /// Gets or sets the value indicating whether to preserve the 
        ///   directory structure.
        /// </summary>
        public bool DirectoryStructure { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, the Directory structure works but I am still having a problem with the compression mode. After creating the zip I changed the mode to "Append" (comp.CompressionMode = SevenZip.CompressionMode.Append;). Though, when executing comp.CompressFiles for the second file it throws an exception: The given key was not present in the dictionary. I can't seem to understand why.